# How can I define an over-arching validation error message for a Symfony Validator Compound / Sequence constraint?

Tags: php, symfony-validator

Using the Symfony Validator, I can create a `Compound` constraint by inheritance:

```
// source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Compound.html
// src/Validator/Constraints/PasswordRequirements.php
namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Compound;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[\Attribute]
class PasswordRequirements extends Compound
{
    protected function getConstraints(array $options): array
    {
        return [
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
            new Assert\Type('string'),
            new Assert\Length(['min' => 12]),
            new Assert\NotCompromisedPassword(),
        ];
   }
}
```

In alternate cases, I could also use `Assert\Sequence` to create a compound constraint that stops at the first validation error:

```
new Assert\Required( [
    new Assert\NotNull(),
    new Assert\NotBlank() // If the value is NULL, there is no need to check for blank
] );
```

The problem is, in both cases, I don't see a way to control the resulting validation error messages.

When using a `Compound` constraint, every validation error is returned. I would prefer to just have an over-arching error message, something like "`Your password is not valid. Please make sure ... etc`".

In the case of a `Sequence`, I would just like to return "`This field is required.`" instead of different variations depending on what exactly went wrong (especially since the user really doesn't need to know the difference between `null` and "blank").

**How can I return an over-arching custom error message for composite constraints like the above?**